# Dynamically setting the reference to a variable used in a method

Tags: c#, dictionary, methods, structure

I am not sure that this title is correct..Anyways I have a class that has a number of methods that control a stereo.  Each method will send a command to a serial port.  There are many models of stereos supported and each stereo may have a different command that needs to be sent.
For example model_A may need to send the command "VOLUP" to the serial port and "model_B" may need to send the command "GAINUP" to increase the volume.  I want to have one method called IncreaseVolume like this:

```
 public void IncreaseVolume()
 {
     serialPort.WriteLine(volumeCommand);
 }
```

This method will be called from another class after setting the model of the radio.  Now for two radios I could do this:

```
public class StereoControl
{
    string volumeCommand;
    string model_A_Volume_Command = "VOLUP";
    string model_B_VOlume_Command = "GAINUP";

    public void Set_Radio_Model(string model)
    {
        if (model == "modelA")
        {
            volumeCommand = model_A_Volume_Command;
        }

        else if (model == "modelB")
        {
            volumeCommand = model_B_Volume_Command;
        }
     }

     public void IncreaseVolume(volumeCommand)
     {
         serialPort.WriteLine(volumeCommand);
     }
}
```

So the main program will first set the model and then anytime the volume needs increasing it will just call the IncreaseVolume method.
The things is that there are potentially dozens of stereos and dozens of commands and I don't necessarily want all these in  if then or case statements.
I thought of creating structures for each model containing the commands but then how do you select which structure to use in the methods?
I am sure there is a more elegant way to do this and am open to suggestions.

The first answer while usable, when we get 100+ commands and 200+ stereo's it will be a bit too difficult to handle.  So here is another possibility but I do not know how to get the class reference available throughout the application.

```
public Class Model_A
{
    string volumeCommand = "VOLUP";
}

public Class Model_B
{
    string volumeCommand = "GAINUP";
}

public Class StereoControl
{
    public void Set_Radio_Model(String model)
    {
        if (model == "model_a")
        {
             var _radio = new Model_A();
        }

         else if (model == "model_b")
        {
             var _radio = new Model_B();
        }
    }

    public void IncreaseVolume()
    {
        serialPort.WriteLine(_radio.volumeCommand);
    }
}
```

Of course the issue here is that the scope of _radio is only within the Set_Radio_Model.  Is there a way to _radio usable everywhere?
Tom

Comment: Basic object oriented design would say create classes for each model that inherit from a parent and handle things in them. No switch cases needed.

Comment: @Tom,Did you see my answer..., any opinion about it?

Comment: Hi, yes, been studying it.  Useful information.  It would seem that the other comment offers a simpler solution.  Create a class for each stereo and then just use that in the StereoController.

Comment: In retrospect this seems it will get pretty busy as the number of commands increases (100+) and the number of stereos increases to 200.  So please look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very basic way is to have Enum of stereos names and then implement it in OOP 
(I hope people help to improve it) this is just depends on my opinion.

1- Define `enum` like:

```
public enum StereoBrand
{
    Stero1 = 0,
    Stereo2 = 1
}
```

2- Define an interface to enforce all stereos implement `IncreaseVolume()` like:

```
public interface IStereo
{
    string VolumeCommand { get; }
    string SteroeName { get; }
    void IncreaseVolume();
}
```

by above interface each stereo should have a name as `StereoName`.

3- And then implement `StereoController` like :

```
public class SteroController : IStereo
{
    public virtual string SteroeName
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    public virtual string VolumeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
    public virtual void IncreaseVolume()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public static SteroController GenerateStereo(StereoBrand brand)
    {
        SteroController stereo = null;
        switch (brand)
        {
            case StereoBrand.Stero1:
                stereo = new Stereo1();
                break;
            case StereoBrand.Stereo2:
                stereo = new Stereo2();
                break;
        }
        return stereo;
    } 
}
```

Notes of Step3:

3.1- `StereoController` implement `IStereo` and change that prop and Increase method to Virtual that all Stereo can override them.

3.2- `GenerateStereo` which create related stereo by its `StereoName`

4- Suppose we have to implement Stereo classes here `Stereo1` and `Stereo2` like:

```
public class Stereo1 : SteroController
{
    public override string SteroeName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Streo1";
        }
    }

    public override string VolumeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return "Command1";
        }
    }

    public override void IncreaseVolume()
    {
        //Do anything with VolumCommand
    }
    public Stereo1()
    {

    }
}
public class Stereo2 : SteroController
{
    public override string SteroeName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Streo2";
        }
    }

    public override string VolumeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return "Command2";
        }
    }

    public override void IncreaseVolume()
    {
        //Do anything with VolumCommand2
    }
    public Stereo2()
    {

    }
}
```

5- The last step is using them like:

```
var stero = SteroController.GenerateStereo((StereoBrand)Enum.Parse(typeof(StereoBrand), "brandName"));
stero.IncreaseVolume();
```

Notes:

N1: This is better to implement `GenerateStereo` by reflection which means find all `IStereo` and make an instance by reflection.

N2: The another solution to avoid `switch-case` is using reflection to find related Stereo like:

```
public static SteroController GenerateStereo(StereoBrand brand)
{
    SteroController stereo = null;
    var type = typeof(IStereo);
    var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()//Find all classes which implemented ISereo
        .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
        .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p)).ToList();
    foreach(Type t in types)
    {
        var stereoNameProp = t.GetProperties().SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == "StereoName");//Get stereo name prop
        if (stereoNameProp != null && stereoNameProp.GetValue(t).ToString() == brand.ToString())//Check it with brand name
            stereo =(SteroController)Activator.CreateInstance(type);//Make an instance
    }  
    return stereo;
}
```

Hope it help and give you the clue.